# Use of const variables that are assigned within a limited scope in C++

Tags: c++, reference, scope

I find myself having a conflict between two best practices, and I was wondering if there is a way of getting the best of both worlds.

I need to get an output from a choice of coordinate systems, and what I would like to do is:

```
// PSEUDO-CODE

const my_class& loads_global();
const my_class& loads_local();

GetLoads(COORDINATES coordinates)
{
    switch (coordinates)
    {
    case LOCAL:
        const my_class& loads = loads_local();
        break;
    case GLOBAL:
        const my_class& loads = loads_global();
        break;
    // etc.
    }
    loads.write();
}
```

The use of const references is good for performance (and this code called a lot), but if it is const it can't be set within a scope delimiter like a switch statement or an if statement (or indeed a try statement, which I've wanted to do before).

I could put the loads.write(); statement within the switch, but in practice it is not just one line, and I hate repeating code.  I could also use pointers instead of references (the "const my_class* const my_object" paradigm), but that does make the code look a lot messier than using references.

Is there a way to use a const reference in the surrounding code, or assign to a const variable which I then won't/can't modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have C++11, you can use a lambda to hide the initialisation:

```
GetLoads(COORDINATES coordinates)
{
    const my_class& loads = [&]() -> const my_class& {
      switch (coordinates)
      {
      case LOCAL:
          return loads_local();
          break;
      case GLOBAL:
          return loads_global();
          break;
      default:
          throw something;
      }
    }();  // Note the call operator here!
    loads.write();
}
```

Comment: We have lambda operators now?!?  As a recovering LISP and then Python developer, this is excellent news!

Comment: @MikeSadler we've them for sometime (4 years) now :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to ask this delicately, but would a puritan get a bit sniffy at this? I missed the introduction of macros, and I'm not sure whether they're fully kosher mainstream, or whether they're regarded as a bit of a work-around...

Comment: @MikeSadler What does this have to do with macros? Anyway, I'm quite heavily on the "prefer code purity" side myself, and find this perfectly fine. If you meant lambdas instead of macros, then they are certainly used a lot (and advocated by many top C++ people).

Answer (score 1):

You could have a third function that returns `const my_class&` and does the switch:

```
const my_class& loads_global();
const my_class& loads_local();

const my_class& GetLoads(COORDINATES coordinates)
{
    switch (coordinates)
    {
    case LOCAL:
        return loads_local();
    case GLOBAL:
        return loads_global();
    }
}

void DoSomething(COORDINATES coordinates)
{
    const my_class& variable = GetLoads(coordinates);
    variable.write();
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this too. But something has to be done for the default case (not LOCAL or GLOBAL.)

Comment: This would definitely be the standard way around the problem - to compartmentalise the code.  I was wondering if there is a way to do it 'in line' - especially in the case of where there is a 'try' statement, which is where I've had this conundrum most often.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
const my_class& loads = (coordinates == LOCAL) ? loads_local() : loads_global();
```

just before the `switch` block?

Comment: Ah, unfortunately my pseudo-code obscured the fact that there are more than two options...

Comment: Then I've to say Angew's is perhaps the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For the give code, why not the following:

```
GetLoads(COORDINATES coordinates)
{
    switch (coordinates)
    {
    case LOCAL:
        loads_local().write();
        break;
    case GLOBAL:
        loads_global().write();
        break;
    }
}
```

Not the most fancy but it skirts the issue of local variables entirely. OK you still have the temporaries, but that can not be avoided.

Comment: That would definitely work in the illustrated case, but I was after a more generic solution, where the use of the variable might be too long to put inside the switch statement.